# Error al renderizar un partial de un controlador desde otro controlador

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando renderizar una tabla de registros de un controlador *Pedidos* en otro controlador llamado *Dashboard*. He leido bastante acerca de hacerlo con:

```
<%= render 'orders/index'%>
```

Y arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Error nil:NilCase]

El codigo actual de mi vista es:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Primera fila de información -->
<div class="row align-content-center">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 border border-dark">
        <h3>Primer Espacio</h3>

        <!-- <%= render 'orders/index' %> -->
        <%=render 'layouts/tables' %>

    </div>
    <div class="col col-sm-6 border border-dark">
        <h3> Segundo Espacio</h3>
        <%=render 'layouts/tables' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

He comentado el código *erb* para evitar el fallo que intento solucionar.El partial es que genera por defecto el comando *Scaffold* en la vista index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Orders</h1>

<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha pedido</th>
      <th>Valorpedido</th>
      <th>Provider</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.fecha_pedido %></td>
        <td><%= order.valorPedido %></td>
        <td><%= order.provider %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', order %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

He leído varios métodos para hacerlo tales como:

```
<%= render :partial 'orders/order', local:{order:@order}%>

<%= render "orders/index", orders: @orders%>
```

Creo que el problema reside en no saber pasar la colección de objetos

```
orders
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Alguien puede ayudarme acerca de como usar correctamente el helper ?

```
<%=render%>
```

El resultado que me gustaría conseguir es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu problema no está en el render, sino en que @orders viene vacío. Si te fijas, el error está sucediendo en la línea 16 de `orders/_index.html.erb`, entonces quiere decir que está cargando ese template

Comment: Claro, el tema es que no se muy bien como pasarle la colección @orders al index de dicho controlador Orders, ya que estoy intentando llamar esta partial desde otra vista y otro controllador (@dashboard).

Comment: Agrega entonces a tu pregunta el código del controlador que carga el partial

Comment: Disuculpa, envío descripción más detallada de lo que me gustaría conseguir al renderizar el partial de otro controlador

Comment: en tu controlador debe de haber un metodo index desde el cual puedes enviar la variable hacia la vista
`código` 
def index
@orders = Order.all
end
`código`

Comment: Pero lo que agregaste no es lo que te solicite. Si tu `@orders` viene vacío, es porque desde *el controlador* está siendo enviado vacío. Ése es el código que deberías agregar a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando intentas renderizar el partial le estas pasando una variable local `orders` en vez de una variable de instancia `@orders`, para solucionarlo, vas a necesitar usar el mismo tipo de variable en ambos lados.

En realidad lo que pasa es que estas rompiendo una convención de Rails que no es tan explícita: las vistas se dividen en `vistas` y *`_partials`*, las vistas se corresponden con una acción de un controller y utiliza variables de instancia (como `orders/index`) y los partials usan variables locales y no se corresponden con ninguna acción ya que se utilizan desde distintas acciones.

Vos lo que estás haciendo es intentar usar una vista como partial y aunque rails *te deja* hacerlo, al final se te complica. Lo que tendrías que hacer es *extraer* un partial con lo que querés compartir y reutilizar ese partial.

El resultado sería el siguiente:

## orders/index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Orders</h1>

<%= render 'orders_table', orders: @orders %>
```

## orders/_table.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Fecha pedido</th>
      <th>Valorpedido</th>
      <th>Provider</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.fecha_pedido %></td>
        <td><%= order.valorPedido %></td>
        <td><%= order.provider %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', order %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</ta
```

ble>

Y en el dashboard utilizas:

## dashboard/index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'orders_table', orders: first_orders %>
```